# Problems with non-ASCII characters in path (Python)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I'm writing a python program that among other things is suppoused to move some files around. One of the directories in the path has a name containing a non-ASCII character:

```
src=os.path.normpath(u'C:\users\Mårten\python\nonpython')
dest=os.path.normpath(u'C:\users\Mårten\python\target')
files=getspc(src)
for mfile in files:
    print "In the loop"
    oldpath=os.path.normpath(os.path.join(src,mfile))
    print "oldpath: ", oldpath
    newpath=os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dest,mfile))
    print "newpath", newpath
    os.rename(oldpath,newpath)
    with dbcon:    
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO spectra VALUES (?, CURRENT_DATE)",[newpath])
```

(Excerpt)

This makes the program crash, claiming that no encoding is declared. How does one declare encoding?

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: The error message goes "*** (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX". When I run this in IDLE I don't get the error message in the shell as you normally do, it comes up in a separate window. The script wont start at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
src=os.path.normpath(u'C:\users\Mårten\python\nonpython')
```

This isn't valid string syntax. Backslashes have special meaning in string literals, so if you want to use a literal backslash you need to escape it:

```
src=os.path.normpath(u'C:\\users\\Mårten\\python\\nonpython')
```

(Unfortunately ‘raw string’ `r''` literals aren't usable here because of the unfortunate design decision that `\u` is still special in raw unicode strings. Boo.)

Also as @user58697 said if you want to use a non-ASCII character in your source code itself you must include a `# encoding: something` line at the top. The `something` should be the encoding you tell your text editor to save the file in—I suggest UTF-8. Unicode is not an encoding. (Except to some Windows editors, which use “Unicode” misleadingly to mean UTF-16LE. You don't want to save as UTF-16 as it's not ASCII-compatible.)

Alternatively you can avoid the problem by using the aforementioned backslash-escapes to name the non-ASCII characters:

```
src=os.path.normpath(u'C:\\users\\M\u00E5rten\\python\\nonpython')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a magic comment. See [PEP 0263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: Is this interpreted, despite being a comment? What should I write to set coding to unicode? I've tried to introduce one of these comments, but it doesn't work.